# MudSelect is not showing selected value

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, blazor, mudblazor

I am facing issue with MudSelect with `MultiSelect="true"`. Even though it has the selected values set it does not check the selected value:

```html
<MudSelect Label="Select Item" SelectAll="true" MultiSelection="true" SelectedValues="@SelectedTestItems" T="@MultiSelectItem" ToStringFunc="@ToString">
    @foreach (MultiSelectItem item in AllItems)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="@item" />
    }
</MudSelect>

@code {
    private List<MultiSelectItem> SelectedTestItems = new() {
        new MultiSelectItem{Id = 1, Name = "Test 1"},
    };

    private List<MultiSelectItem> AllItems = new() {
        new MultiSelectItem{Id = 1, Name = "Test 1"},
        new MultiSelectItem{Id = 2, Name = "Test 2"},
        new MultiSelectItem{Id = 3, Name = "Test 3"},
        new MultiSelectItem{Id = 4, Name = "Test 4"},
    };

    private string ToString(MultiSelectItem x)
        => x is null ? string.Empty : $"{x.Name}";

    public class MultiSelectItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I posted details @github also: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/3532.

Comment: You should post a https://try.mudblazor.com snippet which reproduces your problem. I am pretty sure it will be solved quickly if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you did not override necessary methods for equality comparison. Here is a solution based on your snippet, you can play with it online: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYwPbGvKRlGThZsa

MudSelect uses a HashSet internally, so when you use custom reference types as values you must make sure they have `GetHashCode` and `Equals` based on their data:

```html
<MudSelect Label="Select Item" SelectAll="true" MultiSelection="true" SelectedValues="@SelectedTestItems" T="@MultiSelectItem" ToStringFunc="@ToString">
    @foreach (MultiSelectItem item in AllItems)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="@item" />
    }
</MudSelect>

@code {
    private List<MultiSelectItem> SelectedTestItems = new() {
        new MultiSelectItem{Id = 1, Name = "Test 1"},
    };

    private List<MultiSelectItem> AllItems = new() {
        new MultiSelectItem{Id = 1, Name = "Test 1"},
        new MultiSelectItem{Id = 2, Name = "Test 2"},
        new MultiSelectItem{Id = 3, Name = "Test 3"},
        new MultiSelectItem{Id = 4, Name = "Test 4"},
    };

    private string ToString(MultiSelectItem x)
        => x is null ? string.Empty : $"{x.Name}";

    public class MultiSelectItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public override bool Equals(object o) {
            var other = o as MultiSelectItem;
            return other?.Id==Id;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();
    }


}
```